# python 3.7.1 cannot append inline after split

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, append

I am currently trying to participate in a few one-liner contests and I noticed some weird behaviour that make it hard.

this

`"a,b,c".split(",").append("d")`

returns None, while this:

`l = "a,b,c".split(",")

l.append("d")`

correctly returns ["a","b","c","d"]
Is it a known issue or is it normal behaviour? Documentation says that split returns a list of strings.
I am using python 3.7.1, version from October 22 in the Arch official repos.

Comment: It is normal behaviour. the split(",") function is returning the list. However append does not return the list, it is only modifying it.

Answer (score 2):

`l.append("d")` returns `None` just like the other call. It mutates the list `l` which is called on though (which it also does in the other call, but there you have no reference to the list object):

```
>>> l = "a,b,c".split(",")
>>> l.append("d") is None  # the append call still returns None
True
>>> l  # it does, however, mutate the list
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

In order to get the same result in a single line, you can just use plain concatenation:

```
l = "a,b,c".split(",") + ["d"]
```

If (for some reason) you want to use `list.append` *and* get the resulting list in a one-liner, you would have to resort to some evil-doing like molesting a generator or comprehension for side effects (don't do that in serious code!):

```
l = next(x for x in ("a,b,c".split(","),) if not x.append("d"))
```

Comment: Alright thanks, is there a way to make it append in a single line?